# Create a header for my page

Tags: header-footer, letterhead

Can someone help me to create like this header with LaTeX?

[image]

here is My code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt] {report} %document A4 type rapport

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % les caractère spéciaux

\usepackage[french]{babel}  %traduire les mots anglais en français.

\usepackage{graphicx} %Package pour les images.

\usepackage{geometry} % la margine de la page

\usepackage{fancyheadings}% l'entête et le pied de page

% paramètre de l'entête du page et pied du page

\lhead{\includegraphics[width=60mm, height=20mm]{latex.jpg}}
\chead{}
\rhead{My adress My adress \\My adress My adress \\My adress My adress \\}

\cfoot{}

\pagestyle{fancy}



\usepackage{color} 

\usepackage{setspace} %espace entre paragraphe

\usepackage{enumitem} %package de liste

\usepackage{xcolor} %package de liste

\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}



%\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2cm}

\geometry{top=2cm, bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm}


\begin{document}
\vspace*{5cm}

Text text
\end{document}
```

The result :

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? For the letter itself you could use the »scrlttr2« class from [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). It allows to create letterheads very easy.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I edit my question :)

Comment: Please have a look to [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), chapter 4 and 17. The shown examples can be downloaded from the KOMA-Script homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convenient and package independant way to cutomisze the heder is :

```
\makeatletter
\def\localheading#1{\renewcommand{\@oddhead}{#1}\renewcommand{\@evenhead}{#1}}
\makeaatother
```

yo put in your preamble

Then

```
\localheading{%
 \parbox[20mm]{60mm}{\includegraphics[width=60mm, height=20mm]{latex.jpg}}\hfill%
 \parbox[20mm]{5cm}{My adress My adress \\My adress My adress \\My adress My adress}%
}
```

in place of your `\lhead` and co gives this,  which looks not to bad :
[image]
and you can tune up this results by  adjusting the `inner-pos` parameter of the `\parbox`s, depending on the aligment that j=you prefer for  "my Adress" text.

If the result is too narrow due to the left and right margin, you can surround the content of the header by ab old-fashioned :

```
\hss\hbox to 19cm{ <yoyr herder content> }\hss
```

where `19cm` is the desired width :
[image]

This examples are done with all your packages, with the `article` class but works also with `letter` whith a slight change in your geometry parameters.